# how to insert two javascript variables into HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, getelementbyid

Just want two simple javascript vars to show up as text on the page. This code works for one variable but when I add a second call to `getElementById` it shows nothing:

html

```
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <span id="temper"></span>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = location;

document.getElementById("temper").innerHTML = temp_f;
```

Comment: what is **<p2>** tag ?

Comment: is there any error in the console... and which is the browser used

Comment: is your `temp_f` a declared variable?

Comment: Your code snippet will work fine in at least some browsers...as long as `location` and `temp_f` both have values. Do they?

Comment: i just gave them the value "x" and "y"

Comment: In that case it should work fine. just make sure you run that code in `window.onload`. Can you share where you've defined the `location` and `temp_f` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign the variable `location`, which shadows the built-in:

```js
var location = "x";
```

Instead, change the variable name to something else, for example, `loc`:

```js
var loc = "x",
    temp_f = "y";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = loc;

document.getElementById("temper").innerHTML = temp_f;
```

```html
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <span id="temper"></span>
```